# Installing .NET Framework with program installation

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, installation

I am making installation with Inno Setup Compiler. Program is writen in C# Win Form.

My question is how to make installation which will install .NET Framerowk, becouse program can't work without .NET Framerowk.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Sorry, I missed that you use Inno Setup, but this works for those interested in ClickOnce.

If you are using [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) it's really easy to set that up as one of the prerequisites. I use this in some projects and it works really well.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Download it here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

[.NET Framework 1.1/2.0/3.5 Installer for InnoSetup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetfx_innosetup_instal.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to better to install the .Net runtime when installing the .net applications.